# Convert a datatable into mulitple dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have written code to get data from website for a particular date say 26th feb 2021. the processed data from code is as follows.

| Client Type | Client | DII | FII | Pro |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Future Index Long | 126331 | 584 | 82434 | 27321 |
| Future Index Short | 133088 | 34291 | 40107 | 29184 |
| Option Index Call Long | 1022372 | 267 | 198308 | 310605 |
| Option Index Put Long | 790647 | 12740 | 291494 | 292811 |
| Option Index Call Short | 964795 | 0 | 147444 | 419313 |
| Option Index Put Short | 919882 | 0 | 157139 | 310671 |

I want to convert the dataframe into multiple dataframes an e.g would

**dfclient** should be like this:-

| Date | Future Index Long | Future Index Short | Option Index Call Long | Option Index Put Long | Option Index Call Short | Option Index Put Short |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26-02-2021 | 126331 | 133088 | 1022372 | 790647 | 964795 | 919882 |

what is fastest way to achieve the objective.
I would be required to run a loop as i want data for last 10 business days

entire code is  as follows:-

```
from numpy.core.fromnumeric import transpose
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import xlwings as xw
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *
import requests as req

hols = ["2021-01-26", "2021-03-11", "2021-03-29", "2021-04-02",
        "2021-04-14", "2021-04-21", "2021-05-13", "2021-07-21",
        "2021-08-19", "2021-09-10", "2021-10-15", "2021-11-04",
        "2021-11-05", "2021-11-19"]
hols = pd.to_datetime(hols)

bdays = pd.date_range(end = dt.date.today(),periods=60,freq = BDay())
wdays = bdays.difference(hols)[-10:]
wodays = pd.DataFrame(wdays,columns = ['Business_day'])
wodays['Datestring'] = wodays['Business_day'].dt.strftime("%d%m%Y")



# getting data from NSE website
url = 'https://archives.nseindia.com/content/nsccl/fao_participant_oi_'+wodays.Datestring[0]+'.csv'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
OC = req.get(url,headers=headers).content
data = pd.read_csv(url, header = 1, usecols = [0,1,2,5,6,7,8], index_col = 0  )
data = data.head(4).transpose()
```

Answer (score 0):

For the looping among all date and saving data frame for each date you need to create a dictionary of data frame ... in your case dictionary of **dfclient**

here is a chunk of code you needed

```py
dfclient = {}
for i, date in enumerate(wodays.Datestring):
    # getting data from NSE website
    url = 'https://archives.nseindia.com/content/nsccl/fao_participant_oi_' + date + '.csv'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    OC = req.get(url, headers=headers).content
    data = pd.read_csv(url, header=1, usecols=[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8], index_col=0)
    data = data.head(4).iloc[0]
    data = pd.DataFrame(data).transpose().reset_index()
    data.at[0, 'index'] = dt.date(wdays[i].year, wdays[i].month, wdays[i].day)
    data.rename(columns={'index': 'Date'}, inplace=True)
    dfclient[date] = data
```

Each data frame of **dfclient** you can access by passing datetring of `wodays` as indexkey
i.e. `dfclient['01032021']` or `dfclient['02032021']` you will get your require data frame

Comment: Thanks will review it.